# Change tmux default to zsh

Tags: zsh, tmux

When tmux opens, I would like it to use zsh instead of bash by default. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From `man tmux`:

> default-shell path
>                      Specify the default shell.  This is used as the login shell for new windows when the default-command option is set to empty, and must
>                      be the full path of the executable.  When started tmux tries to set a default value from the first suitable of the SHELL environment
>                      variable, the shell returned by getpwuid(3), or /bin/sh.  This option should be configured when tmux is used as a login shell.

So, in your `tmux.conf`:

```
# set shell
set -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```

and if you want you can add default command each time, when we start a new window:

```
# Retach userspaces
set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```

Comment: remember to `killall tmux` after setting

Comment: `killall tmux` doesn't work here for some reason. I had to `top` and kill all processes individually to reload the config once again

Comment: my tmux would not change until I set the option from the command line: `tmux set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh`

Answer (score 8):

You probably want zsh to be your default shell for most things, then (but this will not apply to cron). The following will make zsh your default shell, and you should then not need to tell tmux anything.

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

Note that some OSs still use `/bin/zsh` as the path to zsh.

Comment: Here's a use case where this is not true: There's a "build" account that is used by multiple people and some of them cannot be bothered to use tmux/zsh all the time. ^_~

Comment: another case is when using tmux itself as default shell

Comment: another case is where chsh is broken, which is true on a particular (unnamed) university's CS servers

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to set it individually for a session, but not for other (future) sessions, you can use

```
 tmux new-session /bin/zsh \; set default-shell /bin/zsh
```